# Extra size in an array (esp +1 to required size) and why do we need it?

Tags: c

I have seen many questions in competitive coding where the array size will always be equal to required size plus 1 (like arr[1001]). Why do we need it ?

I was solving a question in hackerrank where it asked to left rotate the array n times and display it. I solved it in C programming language.

```c
int* rotLeft(int a_count, int* a, int d, int* result_count) {
    int* ra = malloc((a_count) * sizeof(int));
    int rot = d % a_count, i, j;
    *result_count = a_count;
    for (i=rot,j=0;i<a_count;i++, j++)
    {
        *(ra+j) = *(a+i); 
    }
    for (i=0;i<=rot;i++, j++)
    {
        *(ra+j) = *(a+i); 
    }
    return ra;
}
```

But when i try to compile the program:

```
Solution: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 13438]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
```

The above error occurred for only one test case and when increase the malloc size by 1

> int* ra = malloc((a_count + 1) * sizeof(int));

There was no compilation error.

Question Link : [Hackerrank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays)

Comment: Some dudes, especially those from a FORTRAN background, like to 1-base their arrays. Other folk are lazy with their index checking, or it's faster to give yourself an extra element to play with rather checking your bounds. In the latter case it's a sensible choice, especially if you're programming against a clock.

Comment: @user3121023 Thank You. Your correction worked but i cannot understand why only one test case failed when all test cases should have failed.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int rot = d % a_count, i, j;`  for ease of readability and understanding:  Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: There was no compilation error.*  `gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o"
untitled1.c: In function ‘rotLeft’:
untitled1.c:6:32: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
    6 |     int* ra = malloc((a_count) * sizeof(int));
      |                                ^
Compilation finished successfully.`   That last statement from the compiler just means the compiler applied some 'work around'  That does not mean the correct code was created.
`

Comment: The posted code is imissing the `#include` statements and a `main()` function! Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `splits = realloc(splits, sizeof(char*) * ++spaces);

        if (!splits) {
            return splits;`  When `realloc()` fails, this results in a memory leak